# HTML Form Data to SQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, backend

**Information**

I made a PHP script that connects to my database and creates a record in my database. This works. Now, I added a simple form to this page and I want to make a record in my database based on the input that a user gives.

The PHP script without the form:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "detachering";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO medewerkers (voornaam, achternaam, leeftijd, uurloon, opleidingsniveau)
VALUES ('test', 'user', '20', '192', 'HBO')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Medewerker is aangemaakt";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the form that I want to add to it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam">
        <input type="text" name="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam">
        <input type="text" name="leeftijd" placeholder="Leeftijd">
        <input type="text" name="uurloon" placeholder="Uurloon">
        <input type="text" name="opleidingsniveau" placeholder="Opleidingsniveau">
        <button type="submit" name="button">Save</button>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I personally think that it should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO medewerkers (voornaam, achternaam, leeftijd, uurloon, opleidingsniveau)
VALUES ('POST_['voornaam']', 'POST_['achternaam']', 'POST_['leeftijd']', 'POST_['uurloon']', 'POST_['opleidingsniveau']');
```

I haven't done much in PHP, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you get the input vars like so: `$vornaam = $_POST['voornaam']`;

Comment: but you should __not__ put those values directly into your sql-statement, like you've tried. You should use [prepared_statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Please, read about sql injections and prepared statements. You are vulnerable to sql injections!!! Also you should learn about PDO. Since you are learning, learn the latest tech!

Comment: Okay, could you write an example, on how to do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: make sure the form-`action` is correct. Right now you point to a `.html` page, which won't work.

Comment: Lelio, thank you for your suggestion. Since this won't be used in an actual product, this is not a concern at the moment. I will definitely take it in consideration in the future.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: It's a concern **right now**, not later. Do it correctly the first time and you won't get held up on silly mistakes that could easily be avoided. If you skip this and accidentally ship this code the consequences could be catastrophic to your company.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Dear fellow SO'ers... Joey has had his cup of warnings and homework (referrals) today by Jeff, Lelio and tadman Thanks for the sharpness and kindness. No more warnings need after my comment. Let Joey improve his code or post a "self-learning answer" so he can show he did learn from the referrals and help him out once improved code is posted. He'll become a brilliant programmer by improving his answer thereafter. Thank you on behalf of us all (end of reviewing question).

Comment: @Joey ... do improve the safety of your code by editing or post later your self-learned answer as requested by me.

Comment: **Warning: Before you run this example code please check posted comments and answers related to code safety.** This question was reviewed by ZF007 for this particular reason on 2017-01-03-23:33. Thank you

Comment: @Jeff about your *"make sure the form-action is correct. Right now you point to a .html page, which won't work."*. That isn't entirely true. Servers can be configured to treat .html files as php. You should Google that. I'd give you a reference link, but I rather *you* look for it and find it, then read up on articles you will find. Remember, *there's always a method to somebody's madness.* ;-)

Comment: @JoeyDrenth In regards to your *"I personally think that it should be something like:"* - What made you think that and where did you learn about php? I'm curious to know where you got that syntax from, because it's entirely wrong. Have you not read any (worthy) tutorials and/or the (official) manuals at all?

Comment: @ Joey: I'm also curious to know if what @Jeff said earlier about his [*"Right now you point to a .html page, which won't work..."*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067776/html-form-data-to-sql-database#comment83109206_48067776). Was he right or was he wrong? I pinged him about it, stating that that wasn't entirely true. However, if he was right, then the answer you accepted didn't include that part in the answer, therefore this makes your question unclear as is the answer, which I might add, did not even make a simple mention as to why your code failed. They merely dropped in code.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, I know that .html can be interpreted as php. Given the shown complexety of the code I simply assumed a default server configuration and went for the quick hint. But you're of course right, my _"which won't work"_ was wrong wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements for this.
Unfortunately, with mysqli you'll have to use references and cannot just use the POST array directly.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO medewerkers (voornaam, achternaam, leeftijd, uurloon, opleidingsniveau) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
if ($stmt) {
    $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
    $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
    $leeftijd = $_POST['leeftijd']
    $uurloon = $_POST['uurloon'];
    $opleidingsniveau = $_POST['opleidingsniveau'];

    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $voornaam, $achternaam, $leeftijd, $uurloon, $opleidingsniveau);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

edit: Since we are talking about it, here is the PDO example (with connection):

```
try {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'passwd');
    $pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET UTF8');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO medewerkers (voornaam, achternaam, leeftijd, uurloon, opleidingsniveau) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt) {
        $params = [$_POST['voornaam'], $_POST['achternaam'], $_POST['leeftijd'], $_POST['uurloon'], $_POST['opleidingsniveau']];
        $stmt->execute($params);
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Note that I'm creating a new array for the parameters since I'm not sure if there are more values in the POST.

Comment: Good demonstration of `bind_param` but you can skip the single-use variables and just bind to the `$_POST` values.

Comment: Thx, but I think binding the POST directly won't work with mysqli->bind_param, it expects the bound variables as references. PDO would allow it as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you Lars, that worked. I got a syntax error at first, but I saw that you missed a semicolon after ['leeftijd'].

Comment: PDO is a lot better, it's true, however you can bind directly to arrays with the caveat that this bind is directly to the value, and switching the containing array variable, such as inside a loop, won't correctly propagate the switch. Since `$_POST` itself is fixed this isn't a problem.

Comment: One last question though, What does the 'sssss' at the start of bind_param() mean?

Comment: @JoeyDrenth [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) has all the answers to these great mysteries.

Comment: Dropped in code that works is great, but it doesn't answer the (real) question and as to why their code failed in the first place. Maybe not a total fix, but at the very least outline the syntax errors with relevant links to the official manuals on http://php.net

Comment: Haven't you read the initial post? There is no question, there was no error... he asked for advice, and that is what he got.